# Работа с большими объемами данных в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, база-данных, big-data, clickhouse

Сам вопрос: существует ли способ работы с большими объемами данных в питоне, если количество оперируемых строк примерно 1-1,5 миллиарда, а объем ОЗУ ограничен 16ГБ? Структура данных следующая: список кортежей, которые всегда состоят из двух элементов, первый из которых строка, второй - число. Данные выгружаются из БД.
Пример структуры:

```
[
('hgasuhga', 1546873),
('dhfgusure', 68874840),
...
('jaghusglkjasd', 1565748)
]
```

Мне необходимо сгруппировать эти данные в defaultdict, ключом которого будет число, а значением - строка. Соответственно, получится следующая структура:

```
 {
  545158: ['dsh','sryhgesrt','srytg','rstg'],
  5645847568: ['tsst','aers'],
  ...
  698: ['adstg','datss','dtsa']
 }
```

Я могу выгружать данные в список (так примерно раза в 3 быстрее) или сразу в словарь. Мои 16 Гб ОЗУ заканчиваются примерно на 140 миллионах записей, если я использую список, и на 176 миллионах записей, если сразу выгружать в словарь. Рассматривал вариант выгружать данные итерационно, а не все сразу, но тогда группировка не отработает корректно, а будет действовать в пределах выгружаемой итерации (поправьте, пожалуйста, если ошибаюсь).

Comment: проще, быстрее и правильнее сделать это на стороне БД ;) Кстати укажите пожалуйста в вопросе метку вашей БД, т.к. решение может отличаться в зависимости от диалекта SQL /No-SQL  БД

Comment: Проще - согласен, быстрее - вряд-ли, насчет правильнее не знаю. Обработка на стороне базы моих запросов занимает примерно 3 часа, на питоне я это могу сделать за 30 минут примерно. Плюс я в БД и sql не особо уверенно себя чувствую, так что мне проще выгружать данные в питон со скоростью 1.5 миллиона записей в секунду, чем воевать с базой. БД - Clickhouse

Comment: в БД самая медленная операция это чтение данных с диска - в вашем случае вам сначала придется прочитать __все__ данные из БД, потом прогнать их по сети (если БД не на том же сервере) и уже потом обрабатывать полученные данные в Python.

Comment: БД на том же сервере, так что тут проблемы нет. основная проблема в моей слабости с работой в sql, так что проще потерпеть, пока будут выгружены нужные мне данные, чем извращаться с запросами. Кстати, вроде даже если выполнять группировку через запрос, тоже возникают проблемы из-за группировки (использовал Group by). Так что я предпочел все таки работать в питоне.

Comment: пожалуйста, покажите схему таблицы и sql-запрос в ClickHouse; используется ли кластер в CH? как устроен pipeline - данные пишутся постоянно в бд или нет, ремаппинг делается для всего содержимого или нет, как часто это вычисляется? + рассмотрите использование pandas - https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bclickhouse%5Dpandas.

Comment: А почему бы вам не загружать в ОЗУ по примерно 100 миллионов записей, обрабатывать их, выгружать в БД и так продолжать пока записи не кончатся?

Comment: Вам в любом случае придется использовать либо БД либо Hadoop т.к. данные не помещаются в память. Проще всего использовать No-SQL БД, например MongoDB и апдейтить записи по ключу (числу).

Comment: @Elusha в таком случае некорректно будет работать группировка, я это описал в конце вопроса.

Comment: @vladimir, схему не предоставить, конфиденциальная информация, которую я разглашать не могу, насчет кластера не знаю, данные синхронизируются через определенные промежутки времени, насчет ремаппинга не знаю. Вместо pandas рассматривал возможность использования numpy с ее структурированными массивами, но это не целессобразно, так как моя строка может как содержать 10 символов, так и потенциально больше 100.

Comment: Я бы тупо записывал данные в файлы со значением ключа. Если ключей очень много (>10000), то ещё и в каталоги размещать тогда, название каталога - например, первые два символа ключа словаря.

Comment: @Сергей ClickHouse может заранее просчитывать агрегаты - см [AggregatingMergeTree](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/aggregatingmergetree/) - таким образом, он сам будет производить все вычисления, а получение искомого результата будет очень быстрым. У вас есть права на добавление новой табл в CH? Если нет, то вероятно, если рассматривать решение задачи на стороне CH нужно подключать вашего DBA.

Comment: @vladimir прав нет, так что эту сторону пока что оставлю на потом. За ссылку спасибо.

Comment: @CrazyElf можно подробнее? В локальные файлы? Или вы имеете ввиду словари?

Comment: А так вообще можете посмотреть на Dask и Vaex, например, если хотите именно на Python. Не помню что там с такой агрегацией, надо смотреть.

Comment: @Сергей Ну да, все значения, относящиеся к ключу словаря 545158 записывать в файл 54/5158.txt например. Так раскидать данные, а потом уже проще будет их загрузить при необходимости. Просто не очень понятно - а что вы дальше со всем этим делаете, зачем это всё?

Comment: @Сергей приложение должно полагаться на потоковую обработку, чтобы грузить 
 и обрабатывать данные блоками - https://clickhouse-driver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#streaming-results

Comment: @vladimir, можете оформить ваш комментарий в виде ответа и привести небольшой пример? Это явно отвечает на вопрос и сможет помочь тем, кто попадет сюда из поисковиков ;)

Comment: @vladimir именно execute_iter я и использую для загрузки в список (или в словарь) всех нужных мне данных. А потом уже эти данные я группирую, используя особенность питоновских словарей.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для решения я бы рассмотрел 2 пути:

1. ClickHouse side

ClickHouse может заранее просчитывать агрегаты - см [AggregatingMergeTree](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/aggregatingmergetree/) - таким образом, он сам будет производить все вычисления, а получение искомого результата будет очень быстрым.

2. App side

Использование потокового API и обработка данных поблоково с использованием [clickhouse_driver](https://clickhouse-driver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#streaming-results).

```py
from clickhouse_driver import Client

client = Client(host='localhost')

settings = {'max_block_size': 1_000_000}
rows_gen = client.execute_iter(
    # just emulate origin dataset
    'SELECT toString(number % 4096) AS key, number % 1024 AS value '
    'FROM system.numbers '
    'LIMIT 1000111222', settings=settings)

result = {}

for row in rows_gen:
    if row[1] not in result:
        result[row[1]] = []

    result[row[1]].append(row[0])

print(result)
```

*requirements.txt*

```bsh
clickhouse_driver
```